Integers dividing central binomial coefficients

This image is from a paper in which the authors prove that for any primes $p,q$ there are infinitely many $n$ such that $\gcd\left(\binom{2n}{n},pq\right)=1$.
My question is the last paragraph of this page in that paper. Which goes as

Now I don't understand what this paragraph means or what are the conclusions the authors are making. I understand that they are referring to some consequences of the following results they mentioned,
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}f(n)=c_{0} $$
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n\leq x}f^{2}(n)=c^{2}_{0} $$
My question:-
Can you help me deduce the consequences of the above mentioned results they mentioned in that paragraph?
